# Creating a exc jar file in eclipse ?

Tags: java, class, export, executable-jar

so I created a jar file, clicked on export and etc

but when I double click it doesnt do anything

I dont see my classes in the folder

all i see is 
junit
org.hamcrest.core_1.1.0.v2009050107100…

what am i doing wrong ?

Comment: Have you tried executing the jar file from the command line? I.e. `java -jar yourjarfile.jar` Also, eclipse tends to export jars to the last place you exported one, not to your current project directory, so check where it was actually exported to.

Comment: i saved to the desktop, so I could go in the whole folder and see whats in it

Comment: You keep talking about folders. Do you mean you are looking inside the jar file?

Comment: i did this java -jar yourjarfile.jar and it says it could not been reached

Comment: im trying to create a executable jar file that includes the source code files

Comment: faild to load Main-class manifest attributes from ?

Comment: In Eclipse, did you: right-click on your project, select export, select "Runnable JAR file", select the Launch configuration that you use to run your program, and select the output destination? Did the export produce any warnings or errors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your jar is a valid executable

then this should work

```
java -jar your.jar
```

Answer (score 1):

Jar files don't aren't always run by double-clicking.

In order to run the jar file, run the command `java -jar yourjarfile.jar` while in the same directory as the jar file. This assumes that your PATH system variable is set properly.

If you receive an error such as "Failed to load Main-Class manifest attribute from yourjarfile.jar" it means that there is no main class defined in your jar file, and the java interpreter doesn't know where to start.

You can make sure that a main class is specified in Eclipse by exporting as a "Runnable JAR file" and making sure you select a launch configuration that you use to run your program.

In order to list the contents of the jar file, run the command `jar tvf yourjarfile.jar` while in the same directory as the jar file.

In order to extract the contents of the jar file, run the command `jar xvf yourjarfile.jar` while in the same directory as the jar file.

Comment: im using existing manifest from workspace i dont know why it tells me that there is not main class defined in my jar file

Comment: Try using the auto-generated manifest from Eclipse. If your existing manifest does not have a Main-Class specified in it, then your jar file will not be able to run.